# This shirt is a different colour than the other vs This shirt is of a different colour than the other

Tags: word-choice

This shirt is a different colour [from that one].

I assume it's the idiomatic way of saying this. But this seems like equating the shirt with a colour as if the shirt were nothing but that.

Do we also say?
Those films are way lower quality than...
instead of
Those films are of way lower quality...

So generally is it allowed to not use of when what follows be is a noun? Because I feel like we're equating things instead of showing that what follows be is an attribute, which the of construction clearly indicates.

Comment: try to avoid way lower: much lower is better form.

Answer (score 0):

The word "is" has many functions when linking subjects to complements, not just "equality". It often functions to link a description to a subject. Among those functions is this one: "is a different colour" It is quite acceptable for that predicate to link to a subject "This shirt", to describe the colour of the shirt.

English doesn't require you to insert "of" in this kind of structure.

Comment: Thanks. So there is no difference between 
"this shirt is a different colour" 
and 
"this shirt is of a different colour".
Btw, can you point me to someplace that elaborates on this usage of "of" when giving attributes?

Comment: It's difficult to prove, but my feeling is that [of a colour](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/horse+of+a+different+color) was the original way of saying it, but nowadays we usually just say that something is 'a colour'.